# Android kotlin / JAVA - jloop AsyncHttpClient check if extern file exists

Tags: java, android, api, kotlin

This is the code:

```
val url = "http://www.bla.com/file.json"

val client = AsyncHttpClient()
client.get(url, object : JsonHttpResponseHandler()
{
    override fun onSuccess(statusCode: Int, headers: Array<Header>?, response: JSONArray?)
    {
        if(response != null){

            Log.d("letsSee", "file exist")

        }else{

            Log.d("letsSee", "file doesn't exist and android is a pos")

        }
    }

    override fun onFailure(statusCode: Int, headers: Array<Header>?, e: Throwable, response: JSONArray?)
    {
        Log.d("letsSee", "file doesn't exists and android is a pos")
    }
})
```

The code only works when file exist but why don't it do anything when not?? I would like to handle this case!

Comment: what is happening when file is not exist? is it going in onSuccess or on onFailure?

Comment: well nothing! android don't want to admit that it's a pos